# How to fix: expected concrete lifetime, but found bound lifetime parameter

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm currently pulling my hear out over this one. I tried to shrink it down to a minimal reproducible example.

```
struct Request;

struct ResponseWriter<'a> { 
    dummy: &'a () 
}

#[deriving(Clone)]
pub struct RouteStore{
    pub routes: Vec<Route>,
}

#[deriving(Clone)]
struct Route {
    path: String,
    handler: fn(request: &Request, response: &mut ResponseWriter)
}

impl RouteStore {
    pub fn new () -> RouteStore {
        RouteStore {
            routes: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    fn add_route (&mut self, path: String, handler: fn(request: &Request, response: &mut ResponseWriter)) -> () {
        let route = Route {
            path: path,
            handler: handler
        };
        self.routes.push(route);
    }
}

fn main () {

}
```

This leaves me with:

```
error: mismatched types: expected `fn(&http::server::request::Request, &mut http::server::response::ResponseWriter<>)` but found `fn(&http::server::request::Request, &mut http::server::response::ResponseWriter<>)` (expected concrete lifetime, but found bound lifetime parameter )
src/so.rs:12     handler: fn(request: &Request, response: &mut ResponseWriter)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[image]

Previously I stored my `fn` in a `HashMap` like this `HashMap<String, fn(request: &Request, response: &mut ResponseWriter)>`. This worked fine.

But now I want to refactor things a bit and introduced a `Route` struct and store things as `Vec<Route>`. But suddenly hell breaks loose and I don't know how to fix it :-/

For the curious ones, this is part of my effort to write an expressjs inspired web framework for Rust called [Floor](https://github.com/cburgdorf/Floor)

Comment: Could you try reducing it more by replacing the `http` dependency with e.g. `struct Request;` and `struct ResponseWriter<'a> { dummy: &'a () }`?

Comment: Sure, I'll try that. I also pushed the real code here just incase you are curious. https://github.com/cburgdorf/Floor/blob/var_paths/src/routestore.rs

You can just run `make floor` to run into the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After making your example a bit more minimal (getting rid of the `http` dependency), and some suggestions on IRC (namely someone pointing out that the problem goes away if you remove the `deriving(Clone)` from the `Route`), you can see a fixed version below (`--cfg v2`)

```
#[deriving(Clone)]
pub struct RouteStore{
    pub routes: Vec<Route>,
}

#[cfg(v1)]
#[deriving(Clone)]
struct Route {
    path: String,
    handler: fn(response: &mut ())
}

#[cfg(v2)]
struct Route {
    path: String,
    handler: fn(response: &mut ())
}

#[cfg(v2)]
impl Clone for Route {
    fn clone(&self) -> Route {
        Route { path: self.path.clone(), handler: self.handler }
    }
}
impl RouteStore {
    pub fn new () -> RouteStore {
        RouteStore {
            routes: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    fn add_route (&mut self, path: String, handler: fn(response: &mut ())) -> () {
        let route = Route {
            path: path,
            handler: handler
        };
        self.routes.push(route);
    }
}

fn main () {

}
```

<strike>The issue here is that an `fn` does not implement `Clone`.</strike>  (edit: Well, it *does* have a `clone` method, but the returned value does not seem compatible with what that field needs.  The `v2` version above just side-steps the whole issue.)

So I suspect the error you are seeing is coming from the auto-generated clone implementation that `deriving(Clone)` injects.