# Rust lifetime error expected concrete lifetime but found bound lifetime

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime

I am having an issue working with lifetime parameters for structs. I am not 100% sure how to describe the problem, but I created a trivial case that shows my compile time error.

```
struct Ref;

struct Container<'a> {
  r : &'a Ref
}

struct ContainerB<'a> {
  c : Container<'a>
}

trait ToC {
  fn to_c<'a>(&self, r : &'a Ref) -> Container<'a>;
}

impl<'a> ToC for ContainerB<'a> {
  fn to_c(&self, r : &'a Ref) -> Container<'a> {
    self.c
  }
}
```

The error I am getting with this is

```
test.rs:16:3: 18:4 error: method `to_c` has an incompatible type for trait: expected concrete lifetime, but found bound lifetime parameter 'a
test.rs:16   fn to_c(&self, r : &'a Ref) -> Container<'a> {
test.rs:17     self.c
test.rs:18   }
test.rs:16:48: 18:4 note: expected concrete lifetime is the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 16:47
test.rs:16   fn to_c(&self, r : &'a Ref) -> Container<'a> {
test.rs:17     self.c
test.rs:18   }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I have tried many variations and just can't get this thing to compile. I found another post here ([How to fix: expected concrete lifetime, but found bound lifetime parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162518/how-to-fix-expected-concrete-lifetime-but-found-bound-lifetime-parameter)) but is appears to get around the problem instead of solving it. I can't really see why the problem even originates. The &Ref is being passed along via moves so it should just work right?

Any ideas? Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let’s compare the two definitions. First, the trait method:

```
fn to_c<'a>(&self, r: &'a Ref) -> Container<'a>;
```

And the implementation:

```
fn to_c(&self, r: &'a Ref) -> Container<'a>;
```

See the difference? The latter doesn’t have `<'a>`. `<'a>` has been specified elsewhere; the fact that it has the same name does not matter: it is a different thing entirely.

Functionally, your trait definition says that the returned container will have a reference inside it to something from `r`, but *nothing from `self`*. It may use `self` inside the method, but it may not store any references to it in the returned value.

Your method definition, however, is using a `'a` that ties the lifetimes of `r` and the returned `Container` to `self` (that is, to the object itself, not the reference—the ρ₂ in `&'ρ₁ T<'ρ₂>`—it’s a subtle but sometimes significant difference), whereas the trait definition had no such connection.

The two can be made to match by inserting the `<'a>` in the method definition in the implementation. But bear in mind that that is shadowing the `'a` from `ContainerB<'a>`; it is *not* the same `'a`! We’re better to give it another name; for convenience, I’ll make the change the other way round, changing it on the impl instead of the method (either would do):

```
impl<'b> ToC for ContainerB<'b> {
    fn to_c<'a>(&self, r: &'a Ref) -> Container<'a> {
        self.c
    }
}
```

But now of course you have a problem: the return value is of type `Container<'b>` (because that’s what the field `c` in a `ContainerB<'b>` is), but your signature demands `Container<'a>` (something using a reference from `r`, not from `self`).

One way which would fix it is specifying the lifetime of `&self` as `'a` in both the trait definition and the implementation; in the implementation, this would then demand that `'b` was greater than or equal to `'a` (by virtue of the fact that you have successfully taken a reference with lifetime `'a` to an object with lifetime `'b`, and the object must outlive the reference) and so due to the subtyping (`'a` is a subtype of `'b`) `Container<'b>` would be safely coerced to `Container<'a>`.

These sorts of lifetime matters are difficult to think about when you’re not familiar with them; but in time they become quite natural.

Comment: Another fix would be `trait ToC<'a> { fn to_c(&self, r: &'a Ref) -> Container<'a>; }`.

Comment: Oh yes, and then `impl<'a> ToC<'a> for ContainerB<'a>`.

Comment: This certainly helps a lot and fixed some of my wrong thoughts (lifetime shadowing for example)! Thanks. This fixes this case 100%, but I can't seem to apply it to another. I wrote up that question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853111/rust-lifetime-error-expected-concrete-lifetime-part-2)