# Why is this trait/implementation incompatible - bound lifetime vs concrete lifetime

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I'm struggling with this error `rustc` gives me:

```rust
error: method `create_shader_explicit` has an incompatible type for trait: expected bound lifetime parameter 'a, found concrete lifetime
```

My trait declaration is pretty much this:

```rust
pub trait GraphicsContext<R: Resources> {

    /// Creates a shader object
    fn create_shader<'a>(&'a self, shader::Stage, source: &str) -> 
        Result<handle::Shader<R>, shader::CreateError>;

}
```

Here's my implementation,

```rust
pub struct OpenGLResources<'a> {
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a u32> 
}

impl<'a> Resources for OpenGLResources<'a> {
    type Shader = Shader<'a>;
}

impl<'z> GraphicsContext<OpenGLResources<'z>> for OpenGLGraphicsContext {

    /// Creates a shader object
    fn create_shader<'a>(&'a self, stage: shader::Stage, source: &str) -> 
        Result<handle::Shader<OpenGLResources>, shader::CreateError> {

        let shader = Shader::new(self, stage);
        try!(shader.compile_from_source(source));

        Ok(shader)
    }

}
```

In [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847331/rust-lifetime-error-expected-concrete-lifetime-but-found-bound-lifetime) on StackOverflow, they are missing things like `<'a>` between `create_shader` and `()`, however when I compare the fn definitions in mine they look identical.

**EDIT:**

Changing the definition inside `impl` to the following fixes that issue

```rust
fn create_shader<'a>(&'a self, stage: shader::Stage, source: &str) ->     
    Result<handle::Shader<OpenGLResources**<'z>**>, shader::CreateError>
```

But then the issue is that `'a` and `'z` need to be the same lifetime. If I change it to this:

```rust
fn create_shader(**&'z** self, stage: shader::Stage, source: &str) -> 
    Result<handle::Shader<OpenGLResources<'z>>, shader::CreateError>
```

The `impl` block works, but then I need a way of specifying the `'z` lifetime in the trait definition. I tried the following:

```rust
pub trait<'z> GraphicsContext<R: Resources<'z>>
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks the hints of @Chris Morgan I managed to implement this functionality and its now working fine.

If we start with the base trait with the `'a` lifetime included:

```
trait Resources<'a> {
    type Shader: Shader;
    type ShaderProgram: ShaderProgram;
}
```

Then implement it for OpenGL. (note the `PhantomData` struct)

```
struct OpenGLResources<'a> {
   phantom: PhantomData<&'a u32> // 'a is the lifetime of the context reference
}

impl<'a> ResourcesTrait<'a> for Resources<'a> {
    type Shader = Shader<'a>;
    type ShaderProgram = ShaderProgram<'a>;
    type CommandBuffer = CommandBuffer;
    type CommandBufferBuilder = CommandBufferBuilder;
}
```

Its a bit verbose, but the `GraphicsContext` trait works fine too now. The `'a` lifetime goes in the type parameters part.

```
trait GraphicsContext<'a, R: Resources<'a>> {

    fn create_shader(&'a self, ty: Type, source: &str) -> Result<R::Shader, ShaderCreationError>

}
```

Finally this is the required code in the graphics context implementation.
It is extremely verbose with the `'a` lifetimes sprinkled everywhere but at least it works!

```
impl<'a> GraphicsContext<'a, Resources<'a>> for OpenGLGraphicsContext
```

Answer (score 1):

When comparing things like this, you need to remember to expand all the generics so that you can *actually* compare it all. In this case, you haven’t expanded `R`. If you do, the answer becomes obvious: `R` is `OpenGLResources<'z>`, linking the `OpenGLResources` to the `impl` block, whereas your method definition has elided the lifetime on `OpenGLResources`, causing it to be inferred as `self`’s lifetime, which is `'a`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue, but now theres a couple of other problems I added to the question. Would you be able to take a look?

Comment: @neon64: that’s a new issue, really, and one that is probably not surmountable in this design. You may need to look into other ways of representing the trait.